# Aligning multiple runtime generated UILabels in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have a `UITableView` that needs to support content by listing style something like

[image]

But the tricky part is that the amount of "Label" will vary with each cell, some may have only 4 but also up to 12. Also the "Value" can be either a single word or short phrase up to two lines(like in the image above). So I decided to use `UIStackView` to help me pack and size my `UILabels` used to display this. I am currently stuck at a problem when the "Label" varies in length like:
[image]

I need the leading end of the "Values" to be aligned like the first image even though the "Label" vary in length. Is there a behaviour of `UIStackView` that allows so? Or is there another approach that can allow me to obtain the results I need?

Note: Each "Label" and "Value" is in one `UIStackView`, I did it to align them.

I tried using String Formatting too, but "Values" with more than one line will wrap under the label instead of wrapping by itself like I manage to do in the images.

I tried placing all "Labels" in one `UIStackView` and all "Values" in another, I could no get them to align like they do in the images once the "Value" is more than one line.

Or if it might be a mistake I made somewhere, this is how I created the `UIStackViews`:

```
    var higherCount = 0
    if labels.count<values.count {
        higherCount = values.count
    } else {
        higherCount = labels.count
    }

    mainStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))

    for i in 0..<higherCount {
        var height:CGFloat = 20
        if (values[i] as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]).width > frame.width {
            height = 42
        }

        let stackViewToAdd = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: height))

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: height))
        if labels.count<higherCount {
            label.text = ""
        } else {
            label.text = labels[i]
        }
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(999, for: .horizontal)
        stackViewToAdd.addArrangedSubview(label)
        let value = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: height))
        if values.count<higherCount {
            value.text = ""
        } else {
            value.text = values[i]
        }
        value.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        value.numberOfLines = 2
        stackViewToAdd.addArrangedSubview(value)
        mainStackView?.addArrangedSubview(stackViewToAdd)
    }
    mainStackView?.alignment = .fill
    mainStackView?.axis = .vertical
    mainStackView?.distribution = .fill
```

Comment: you can use self sizing tableview cells

Comment: @VinupriyaArivazhagan can you explain more? I tried using that but because my entire cell is created programatically, the cell will not resize at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  you created your cell programmatically, then you can resize the cell programmatically depends on the size of UILabel Content.

In my case `Label` font is `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)`, minimum TableViewCell height is 50, `arrLabel1` and `arrLabel2` will be the content of Labels.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrLable1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "\(indexPath.row)")

    let lable1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 0))
    lable1.numberOfLines = 0
    lable1.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    lable1.text = arrLable1[indexPath.row]
    lable1.sizeToFit()
    cell.addSubview(lable1)

    let lable2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: lable1.frame.origin.y + lable1.frame.size.height + 10 , width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 0))
    lable2.numberOfLines = 0
    lable2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    lable2.text = arrLable2[indexPath.row]
    lable2.sizeToFit()
    cell.addSubview(lable2)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> CGFloat {

    let boundingRect1 = arrLable1[indexPath.row].boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width - 40 , height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,attributes:[ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)] ,context: nil)

    let boundingRect2 = arrLable2[indexPath.row].boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width - 40 , height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,attributes:[ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)] ,context: nil)

    guard boundingRect1.height + boundingRect2.height + 30 > 50 else {
        return 50
    }

    return boundingRect1.height + boundingRect2.height + 30
}
```

> > Set `Label` numberOfLines to 0

Comment: Thanks, that's useful but It didn't solve my problem. The main problem I have is the alignment of multiple Labels in the cell. I did some sort of calculation to set the height of the cell, though I'd try yours to see if it works better. But I need to way to align the content neatly in the Label to Value relation.

Comment: set Label1 content, set Label1 sizeToFit(), get frame from Label1. Do the same for all Labels. then set  'y' position for all Labels depends on the Labels frames. Then realign the frame. You can use above code to get UITableViewCell Height.

Comment: So you suggest I calculate the position of each Label using it's calculated size instead of using `UIStackView`?

Comment: see my updated answer.. In my point of view UIStackView is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I worked on the codes you have and improved it to support multiple UILabels like I needed it, can you review and confirm the edit?